# Merge Two CSV Files Using Two Common Keys

Tags: csv, powershell

Hello I Used below code to *Merge* CSV files using one common Key for adding one column from `Child.CSV` to `Parent.CSV`.

```
    {
        Import-Csv "D:\CSV check\Sourcecount.csv" -Header Sourcecount, MONTH_YEAR | ForEach-Object -Begin {
            $Employees = @{}
        } -Process {
            $Employees.Add($_.MONTH_YEAR,$_.Sourcecount)
        }

        Import-Csv "D:\CSV check\RenameFinal.csv" | ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Sourcecount -Value $Employees."$($_.MONTH_YEAR)" -PassThru
        } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "D:\CSV check\sourcefinal.csv"
    }
```

**Question:**
        Can you please help for the scenario joining for getting one column value from child.csv to Parent.csv for two common keys (by data and by userid).

Comment: Can you show us a sample data set?

Comment: Thank you Mathias For Response. I tried using added code and able to get the required results.

Comment: Great! Please post your solution *as an answer* so it won't be listed as "unanswered" :)

Comment: Please add your answer separately by clicking on Add An Answer button below. Do not add the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I used to solve the above Query:

```
$f2=Import-Csv "D:\Sourcecount.csv" -Header Sourcecount,MONTH_YEAR,UserID
$f1= Import-csv "D:\Final.csv" -Header MONTH_YEAR,DestinationCount,UserID,Result,SourceCount

$f1|
%{
  $Month_YEAR=$_.MONTH_YEAR
  $UserID=$_.UserID
  $m=$f2|?{$_.MONTH_YEAR -eq  $Month_YEAR}|?{$_.UserID -eq  $UserID}
  $_.SourceCount=$m.Sourcecount
}
$f1| Export-Csv "D:\SourceFinal.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```